# Unix bash: select rows with unique value in one column, based on value of another column

Tags: bash, awk, unique

I have a file with two columns that looks something like this:

```
1 3
1 4
2 3
3 3
4 3
4 4
```

I want to make this into a file with unique values in the first columns, and of the duplicate rows only keep the rows with the largest values in the second column, so the new file looks like this:

```
1 4
2 3
3 3
4 4
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using bash/awk/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can manage this using an associative array that has key as column-1 and value as maximum of column-2:

```
awk '$2 > a[$1]{a[$1] = $2} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file

1 4
2 3
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: This is great, it works! I do not quite understand how yet unfortunately...
What if I had three columns, and I wanted to select rows that were unique based on the first two columns combined, and select them based on the maximum value of the third column? Can this awk command be amended to do that?

Comment: Yes it can be done. `awk '$3 > a[$1,$2]{a[$1,$2] = $3} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file`

Comment: You might want to use `a[$1 FS $2]` instead of `a[$1,$2]` if you're going to print the indices.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you, it will provide you the latest values only for $1 along with non-duplicate values in same order in which Input_file's $1 are there.

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++i]=$1} {a[$1]=$0;} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print a[b[j]]}}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

use simply `sort`:

```
sort -k2,2rn file|sort -uk1,1n
```