# In PostgreSQL, return rows with unique values of one column based on the minimum value of another

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

**Background**

I've got this `PostgreSQL` join that works *pretty* well for me:

```
select  m.id,
        m.zodiac_sign,
        m.favorite_color,
        m.state,
        c.combined_id
from people."People" m
LEFT JOIN people.person_to_person_composite_crosstable c on m.id = c.id
```

As you can see, I'm joining two tables to bring in a `combined_id`, which I need for later analysis elsewhere.

**The Goal**

I'd like to write a query that does so by picking the `combined_id` that's got the lowest value of `m.id` next to it (along with the other variables too). This ought to result in a new table with unique/distinct values of `combined_id`.

**The Problem**

The issue is that the current query returns ~300 records, but I need it to return ~100. Why? Each `combined_id` has, on average, 3 different `m.id`'s. I don't actually care about the `m.id`'s; I care about getting a unique `combined_id`. Because of this, I decided that a good "selection criterion" would be to select rows based on the lowest value `m.id` for rows with the same `combined_id`.

**What I've tried**

I've consulted several posts on this and I feel like I'm fairly close. See for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277801/selecting-rows-based-on-minimum-value-of-one-column) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54252163/select-unique-rows-based-on-single-distinct-column-mysql). [This other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824592/unix-bash-select-rows-with-unique-value-in-one-column-based-on-value-of-anothe) does *exactly* what I need (with `MAX` instead of `MIN`) but he's asking for it in Unix Bash

Here's an example of something I've tried:

```
select  m.id,
        m.zodiac_sign,
        m.favorite_color,
        m.state,
        c.combined_id
from people."People" m
LEFT JOIN people.person_to_person_composite_crosstable c on m.id = c.id
WHERE m.id IN (select min(m.id))
```

This returns the error `ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres's `DISTINCT ON` is probably the best approach here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.combined_id)
    m.id,
    m.zodiac_sign,
    m.favorite_color,
    m.state,
    c.combined_id
FROM people."People" m
LEFT JOIN people.person_to_person_composite_crosstable c
    ON m.id = c.id
ORDER BY
    c.combined_id,
    m.id;
```

As for performance, the following index on the crosstable might speed up the query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON people.person_to_person_composite_crosstable (id, combined_id);
```

If used, the above index should let the join happen faster.  Note that I cover the `combined_id` column, which is required by the select.

Comment: Clicking refresh so fast I went with your first draft that had `SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.id)` instead of `combined_id`, which yielded the same ~300 rows  The new version worked perfectly. I'd tried variations on `SELECT DISTINCT` but didn't bump into `SELECT DISTINCT ON`. Is it unique to Postgres?

Comment: @logjammin Yeah... `DISTINCT ON` is totally unique to Postgres, though some other databases have similar things (such as SQL Server).  By the way, the second edit of my answer actually matches what you asked for in the question.  But I have reverted as the first version seems to be what you really want.

Comment: Oh wait no, don't revert -- maybe I messed up in my question but that second version you had (`SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.combined_id)`) is the one I needed, as I want a table with unique `combined_id`'s, and whichever `m.id` that appears next to it is fine.